# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )",

Tags: javascript

I know a similar question has be asked but none helped in my case.

I am developing a Cordova app. I ran series of test on the app and everything (Navigation, Web Service call) works fine using my system browsers(IE and Mozilla)

Now using Eclipse, From the Emulator, I tried to log-in to the app (Authentication should invoke the webservice) but nothing happens.

On checking the LogCat I saw an Exception:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )", Source: File:///android_asset/www/login.html

Here is the .js script part:

```
$(document).on('click', '#S_IN', function() {
  if (($('#username').val() == "") || ($('#password').val() == "")) {
    alert("All fields are required.");
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "username": $('#username').val(),
        "password": $('#password').val()
      }),
      url: "http://127.0.0.1/appName/Service.asmx/Authenticate",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        if (JSON.parse(data.d).toLowerCase() == 'success') {
          $.mobile.changePage('main.html');
        } else {
          alert("Login failed. Invalid Username or Password combination.");
        }
      },

      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
      }
    });
  }
});
//..............................Login End........................//
```

Pls what am I doing wrong? I'm stuck.

Comment: should see what's in `xhr.responseText`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure you even want to use `eval` in the first place. That's what *JSON* is for (assuming `xhr.responseText` is a stringified object).

Comment: So your response is a JSON object with a property whose value is a JSON-encoded *string*?  Really?

Comment: You sure this is the only JS? What's the response text look like (evil eval, btw)?

Comment: As pointed @Pointy the error may be from `JSON.parse`. check what's in `data.d`

Answer (score 2):

Imaxo, your code style isnt so good, you need to do the follow things:

1. Procces data after DOM/window is loaded
2. declare variables
3. do not attach events to document(except keyboard events which should
   fired without form)
4. prepare data before put it to request

and here is the small example:

firstFile.js

```
var app = app || {};

app.auth = (function(){

    return {
        initialize: function(){
            //declare variable
            //this.variable = global for this object
            //var some; = local for this method
        },
        validate: function(){
            //validate data
        },
        send: function(){
           //send AJAX request
        }
        //other methods
    }

})();
```

secondFile.js

```
var app = app || {};
$(function(){
    app.auth.initialize();
});
```

this is revealing modular pattern with basic module organization pattern, but better look at require.js

asnwering your question, somewhere in your code you write excess ")"